# Prevent a certain package from autoupdating

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I'd like to disable/remove autoupdate for the certain packages in a repository. In particular, I want this package to stop autoupdating:

[image]

I just don't want to install it. Is it possible to prevent it from appearing each time I boot my comp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable it via terminal with apt-mark

```
sudo apt-mark hold onboard
```

to allow updating again use "unhold"

```
sudo apt-mark unhold onboard
```

---

Extra information:

- [apt-mark manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/apt-mark.8.html)
- `man apt-mark`
- A more detailed answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Comment: how do I know the proper name of the package?

Comment: it is "onboard"

run:

`sudo apt-mark hold onboard`

Comment: in this case yes, it's on board, but if it was something like "my super Module package for Ubuntu 14"?

Comment: I usually just google the package and than it takes be to the package page on [ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) , [ubuntu updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/), or [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). A better way may be using the `apt-cache my-super` command. it will try to search for the name and return the package name.